# Removing width styling from certain tabs in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have the following ui.R file:

```
library("shiny")
library("plotly")
library("shinythemes")
library("shinyjs")

shinyUI <- fluidPage(title = "LoL Analysis", theme = shinytheme('sandstone'),

            tags$head(
            tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "style.css")
            ),

             navbarPage(strong("League of Legends"),
               tabPanel("Project Overview"),
               tabPanel("Player Analysis",
                 sidebarLayout(
                   sidebarPanel(
                     selectInput(inputId = "role",
                       label = "Choose a role:",
                       choice = c("Top", "Jungle","Middle", "ADC", "Support",
                       selected = "Middle")),
                     br(),
                     uiOutput("firstdropdown"),
                     br(),
                     uiOutput("seconddropdown")
                   ),
                   mainPanel(
                     h2("Overview"),
                     p("Some long paragraph")

                   )
                 )
               ), 
               tabPanel("How to win more games?", class =  "two",
                        mainPanel(
                          h2("Overview"),
                          p("Some long paragraph"),
                        )),
               tabPanel("Sources/Contact Us")
             )
)
```

And here is the style.css:

```
.col-sm-8{
    width: 100%;
}
h2{
    color: white;
    background: slategray;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

The problem I am having is that because I have a sidebar layout under the tab "Player Analysis", I do not want the width to be 100%. (Just the default width for the main panel is fine). However, for the "Project Overview" and the "How to win more tab" Ill like the width to be 100% because there are no side panels. I don't know much about CSS, but I tried create a class called "two" and tried `two.col-sm-8{}` in CSS instead, which did not work. Any help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you have some different choices. Your problem comes from that `mainPanel` creates a div with class `col-sm-8`.

The first solution would be to skip the `mainPanel` altogether and just put the content in a `fluidRow` for example this will give the the full width of the screen.

The second solution if you want to keep `mainPanel` but want to use the whole width of the screen anyway and you know the app will almost always run on a big screen you can add the class `col-md-12` to the `mainPanel` this class will overrule the `col-sm-8` class on medium to large screens and will give you the whole width of the screen. I have implemented both in the example below

```
library(shinythemes)
library(shinyjs)
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(title = "LoL Analysis", theme = shinytheme('sandstone'),

                     tags$head(
                       tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "style.css")
                     ),

                     navbarPage(strong("League of Legends"),
                                tabPanel("Project Overview",
                                         fluidRow(
                                           div("sometext")
                                         )),
                                tabPanel("Player Analysis",
                                         sidebarLayout(
                                           sidebarPanel(
                                             selectInput(inputId = "role",
                                                         label = "Choose a role:",
                                                         choice = c("Top", "Jungle","Middle", "ADC", "Support",
                                                                    selected = "Middle")),
                                             br(),
                                             uiOutput("firstdropdown"),
                                             br(),
                                             uiOutput("seconddropdown")
                                           ),
                                           mainPanel(
                                             h2("Overview"),
                                             p("Some long paragraph")

                                           )
                                         )
                                ), 
                                tabPanel("How to win more games?", class =  "two",
                                         mainPanel(
                                           class = "col-md-12 col-sm-12",
                                           h2("Overview"),
                                           p("Some long paragraph")
                                         )),
                                tabPanel("Sources/Contact Us")
                     )
)

srv <- function(input, output){

}

shinyApp(ui, srv)
```

Hope this helps!